# Automated login script in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a python script that helps me to login into my gmail account when run. I took a quick look at the gmail login page and it was like 2000 lines. Most of it was css and some script. What i want is the script to contain my login details and send them when ran.

Comment: The problem here is that your browser is being sent a session cookie that will authenticate it once you've entered the correct credentials. Even if you managed to write a python script, you'd have to inject that cookie into your browser to authenticate yourself there too.

Comment: Tnx for the reply. I dont need to authenticate myself in the browser. I dont have the need for a browser at this point. I just want to check wether the details i sent are correct. Is that possible?

Comment: Check out the form, pick the `action` and `method` attributes and fill the `input` fields manually, should be doable I guess...

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Login your usual browser through a script? Test that login/pwd are ok? Connect to gmail and programmatically do stuff with your emails?

Comment: @lajarre: I want to confirm that the login details are correct. That is the part that interests me the most for now

Answer (score 2):

```
import smtplib
# Set connection. This has to be using TLS
connection = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
# Say hello, god knows why
connection.ehlo()
# Start TLS session
connection.starttls()
# Try to login with email/pwd
connection.login('myemail@gmail.com', 'mypwd')
# Close it
connection.close()
```